# Create text file dynamically in a specified directory, write data,read data from that file in java

Tags: java, file, filewriter

Recently i have tried to write code of above given title and the problem is that i could not get sufficient date to write upon have a look at my code .it is showing some errors like

it is showing invalid token for semicolon after tagfile.createnewfile();
 let us look at code:

public class WriteToFileExample {

```
String path = "G:"+File.separator+"Software"+File.separator+"Files";

 String fname= path+File.separator+"fileName.txt";

boolean bool=false;

    File f = new File(path);

    File f1 = new File(fname);

    try {

        f1.createNewFile();

        bool=f.mkdirs() ;

    } catch (IOException e) {

        // TODO Auto-generated catch block

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
private static final String FILENAME = "G:\\Software\\Files\\anil.txt";

static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String content = null;

    String[] str = new String[100];

    try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(FILENAME))) {

        System.out.println(" enter no.of line to be inserted into file");

        int k = sc.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i <= k; i++) {

            System.out.println(" enter " + i + " line data");

            content = sc.nextLine();

            bw.write(content);

            str[i] = content;

        }

        System.out.println("The content present in\n
```

G:\Software\Files\anil.txt is:");

```
        for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++)
            System.out.println(str[i]);

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}
```

}

Comment: What errors? Please show them in your question.

Comment: Also paste what errors you are facing

Comment: it is showing invalid token for semicolon after tagfile.createnewfile();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find the code and then you can use

```
**Writing** : PrintWriter,Scanner,BufferedWriter etc to write to that file
**Reading** :FileReader,BufferReader,Scanner with these readers etc

String path = "G:"+File.separator+"Software"+File.separator+"Files";
    String fname= path+File.separator+"fileName.txt";
        File f = new File(path);
        File f1 = new File(fname);
        f.mkdirs() ;
        try {
            f1.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Ref : https://www.lynda.com/Java-tutorials/Reading-writing-text-files/107061/113497-4.html

Refer above video which may help

Comment: It is showing some errors at f.mkdir(); like                                      Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error on token "mkdirs", Identifier expected after 
  this token
 - Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token                        please help me out..!!!

Comment: Hi Shanmukh this is just a snippet bro.You need to write your custom  logic.I think you might have missed some parenthesis.Can you please put your complete code to the question

Comment: Hi Avinash,You really need to know the basics of java .Why have u closed the parenthesis  for class before the method ends ...Check the parenthesis where it is started and ended will give a compete code tmrw.Do some googling

Comment: Double click on open parenthesis in eclipse it will only show the scope of parenthesis

Comment: Glad that you got that issue fixed.Can you accept this as answer